# JQM predefined table border style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Which standard (predefined in JQM CSS) style(s) responsible for JQM table border?
I need to set table border color same as background in standard theme "b" (blue border).
Guess no need to invent my own style and need to override (use) existing one. But which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `table-stroke` class which sets borders on table rows to:

```
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6; /* non-RGBA fallback */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
```

Here is the page from the JQM [api tables](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/)